# UWP App Build Fails

Tags: uwp

I have a medium size solution (40+ projects), most of them are .Net framework 4.7.1 and .Net Standard 2.0.
As an extra there is an UWP App too, which was working well before, but now I got the following error message:

Framework resource extraction failed. Item named 'themes/images/desktopalerticonblue.png' of type 'System.IO.PinnedBufferMemoryStream' cannot be added to the resource file because it is not serializable. My UWP App...

It's strange because I don't reference any "desktopalerticonblue.png" directly.

Can you give me any idea how to solve it, or start debugging it to find the real problem?

Comment: Do you have any change with the uwp project until it doesn't work? What is your device OS version and build? Will the issue happen in a new blank uwp app?

Comment: Yes, I am continuously processing changes on the project (nuget, extensions, 3rd party tools, vs2017 etc.. updates) and I was a bit lost what went wrong.
Luckily I found the problem, I am trying to create an "universal" .Net Standard DevTools project what I plan to use in general in all of my applications, and the self made ViewModelBase class (containing a WPF related Window object) caused this mysterious error. By removing it the UWP app starts well again.

My conclusion:
Be very cautious when mixing up different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the similar issue. The reason was referenced normal .net assembly.
After I removed the reference, it started to work fine.